# Buggy close event on sub modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I m having a problem when a modal open another modal.
When i hit close button on sub modal, it does not close, need to click it twice before it trigger the close event.
Already used  `data-target="#target"` but the problem still there.
Is there a way to fix this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Brvfn/4/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle, I couldn't get the 'close' to work either so I tested it at http://bootply.com/62061 (using the latest Bootstrap 2.3.2 and jQuery 1.9.1) and everything worked fine.

Assuming it must be the older Bootstrap, I updated your fiddle to Bootstrap 2.3.2 and it still didn't work.

So.. the problem seems to be with jQuery 1.8.3 and Bootstrap.